# How to Solve Method Not allow Must be one of: PUT IN php

Tags: php

I am writing a php in this i got error message in output

> Method not allowed. Must be one of: PUT
>   here is my php codes

```
$h[]='Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8';
$h[]='User-Agent: okhttp/3.9.1';

$postdata='{"my_link":"abcd1234"}';
$url=http://myurl.com
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$h);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);

$output=curl_exec($ch);
echo "$output";
```

How to solve this problem guys help me out for this

Comment: the url should be quoted like `$url = "http://myurl.com";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by way of example. request tested with **Postman**:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "53632",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://myurl.com:53632/api/todo/1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => " {'my_link': 'abcd1234' }",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json"   
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) 
{
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} 
else
{
  echo $response;
}
```

You can use a custom request method:

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT"//GET,DELETE
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a
>   HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure
>   HTTP requests.

Note:

> Don't do this without making sure the server supports the custom
>   request method first.